# PopUpWindow and null object reference

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, binary, sockets

I've been struggling with this problem for last few hours but still got no idea what's wrong. Here's the scenario:

Application built on top of the Mate framework sometimes need to exchange data with remote server over plain binary socket.

When specific packet is received I have to switch view (using ViewStack) and create custom panel (using PopUpManager class). This custom panel contains a dataGrid component which has to be populated with some XML received along with mentioned packet.

Trouble is that when I try to assign XML to DataGrid's dataProvider I constantly get "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" error. The only thing I can think of is some kind of race when processing events and creating components.

Here are the most interesting pieces of code:

```
<!-- LoginEvent.LOGIN_OK _____________________________________________________________________ -->

<EventHandlers type="{LoginEvent.LOGIN_OK}">

    <MethodInvoker generator="{UserManager}" method="storeCurrentUser" arguments="{event.fullName}"/>
    <EventAnnouncer generator="{NavigationEvent}" type="{NavigationEvent.MAIN}"/>
    <MethodInvoker generator="{CustomSocket}" method="listBoards"/>
```

In the above code I react when the LOGIN_OK packet is received.

Store user's data, change the view and ask the Socket class wrapper to send request (the reponse for that request is our **verySpecificPacket**)

Here's detailed info about how I change the view and create custom pop up. In MainUI.mxml:

```
<mate:Listener type="{NavigationEvent.MAIN}"    method="handleNavigationEvent" />

private function launchBoardListWindow():void {
   Logger.info("launchBoardListWindow()");
   var win:BoardList = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, BoardList, true) as BoardList;
   PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
}

private function handleNavigationEvent(event:NavigationEvent):void {

   viewStack.selectedIndex = MAIN;
   launchBoardListWindow();
}
```

The third position in EventMap isn't important, it just ask socket wrapper to send some kind of packet. The server is supposed to respond with **verySpecialPacket** along with XML payload. And here we are at the part where the error is. In mxml describing my custom panel I set up a listener for an event which is being dispatched after my **verySpecialPacket** is received.

```
public function handleListBoardsEvent(e:ListBoardsEvent):void {

   Logger.info("handleListBoardsEvent");        
   xmlData = e.xml;     
   boardList.dataProvider = xmlData.children(); // Here's the error!!!
}
```

I really don't get it, since the xmlData is OK, and custom panel with all child components were created. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You're likely on the right track in respect of a race condition.

Suggestion:

Put a try { ... } catch (e:Error) { trace("error"); } block around the code in your handleListBoardsEvent() method.

Then, put a breakpoint on the trace() and, when it hits, take a good look around at the various objects involved.

My guess is that you're attempting to access the boardList object before it is created - i.e. it's null.

The other possibility is that boardList.dataProvider is a setter and there's code in the setter that's barfing. (Although, if that were the case, I'm sure you would have noticed the stacktrace inFlexBuilder)